# New Contact Form Not Working URL was not found on this server

Tags: php, html, forms, web, contact-form

I'm fairly new and was wondering if anyone could help. I've just uploaded all website files via filezilla to a web hosting company and the contact form isn't working. I've tried looking into this but I can seem to find out why. Are you able to have a look at my code and see if I'm perhaps missing something.

**The Contact Form**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="Contact Protekt Insurance Brokers. For more information and questions you have">
    <meta name="keywords" content="insurance companies, cheap car insurance, insurance brokers, insurance, personal insurance, business insurance, home insurance, life insurance, insurance agency, car insurance, insurance quotes, cheap insurance, liability insurance">
    <meta name="author" content="Vaughan Testa">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha256-h20CPZ0QyXlBuAw7A+KluUYx/3pK+c7lYEpqLTlxjYQ=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/utilities.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <title>Contact Protekt | Protekt Insurance Brokers</title>
</head>

<body id="home">
    <header class="hero blog">
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar top">
            <h1 class="logo">
                <span class="text-primary">Protekt </span>Insurance Brokers</h1>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="downloads.html">Documentation</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <h1 class="text-primary">Contact Us By Email</h1>
        </div>
    </header>

    <main>
        <section id="contact" class="contact flex-columns">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <div class="column-1">
                        <img src="images/blogger-336371_1920.jpg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <div class="column-2 bg-light">
                        <h2>Contact Us By Email</h2>
                        <form action="process.php" method="POST" id="contact_form" class="callback-form">
                            <div class="form-control">
                                <label for="name"></label>
                                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter name" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-control">
                                <label for="email"></label>
                                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-control">
                                <label for="phone"></label>
                                <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Enter phone" />
                            </div>
                            <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit" class="btn" />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="about" class="icons bg-primary">
            <h2 class="about-h2">Contact Details</h2>
            <div class="flex-items">
                <div class="flex-item1">
                    <i class="fas fa-phone fa-2x"></i>
                    <div>
                        <h3>Contact Info</h3>
                        <p>
                            Telephone: (09) 475 6602 <br>International Callers: +649 475 6602
                        </p>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-item2">
                    <i class=" fas fa-envelope fa-2x "></i>
                    <div>
                        <h3>Email Info</h3>
                        <p>
                            E-mail: enquiry@protekt.co.nz
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-item3">
                    <i class="fas fa-address-card fa-2x"></i>
                    <div>
                        <h3>Office Location</h3>
                        <p>
                            103 Glenvar Road, <br>Torbay, Auckland 0630 <br>New Zealand <br><br>Postal Address<br>PO Box 35962 <br>Browns Bay <br>Auckland 0753 <br>New Zealand
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="boxes">
            <div class="container-boxes">
                <div class="box">
                    <img src="images/steadfast.gif" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <img src="images/ANZ.gif" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <img src="images/IBANZ.gif" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>

    <footer class="footer bg-dark">
        <div class="social">
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a>
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/feed/?trk=eml-wym-cta&midToken=AQH5aDYsgxFjzQ&trkEmail=eml-what_you_missed_v2-null-9-null-null-3408xn%7Ekdhu7th4%7Evu-null-neptune%2Ffeed" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-2x"></i></a>
        </div>
        <p>Copyright &copy; 2020 - Designed By: Vaughan Testa</p>
    </footer>

    <script>
        const navbar = document.getElementById('navbar');
        let scrolled = false;

        window.onscroll = function() {
            if (window.pageYOffset > 100) {
                navbar.classList.remove('top');
                if (!scrolled) {
                    navbar.style.transform = 'translateY(-70px)';
                }
                setTimeout(function() {
                    navbar.style.transform = 'translateY(0)';
                    scrolled = true;
                }, 200);
            } else {
                navbar.classList.add('top');
                scrolled = false;
            }
        };
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

My PHP Code

```
 <?php

if(!$_POST) exit;

$email = $_POST['email'];

error_reporting(error_reporting() & ~E_DEPRECATED);

//$error[] = preg_match('/\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i', $_POST['email']) ? '' : 'INVALID EMAIL ADDRESS';
if(!eregi("^[a-z0-9]+([_\\.-][a-z0-9]+)*" ."@"."([a-z0-9]+([\.-][a-z0-9]+)*)+"."\\.[a-z]{2,}"."$",$email )){
    $error.="Invalid email address entered";
    $errors=1;
}
if($errors==1) echo $error;
else{
    $values = array ('name','email','message');
    $required = array('name','email','message');
     
    $your_email = "enquiry@protekt.co.nz";
    $email_subject = "New Message: ".$_POST['subject'];
    $email_content = "new message:\n";
    
    foreach($values as $key => $value){
      if(in_array($value,$required)){
        if ($key != 'subject' && $key != 'company') {
          if( empty($_POST[$value]) ) { echo 'PLEASE FILL IN REQUIRED FIELDS'; exit; }
        }
        $email_content .= $value.': '.$_POST[$value]."\n";
      }
    }
     
    if(@mail($your_email,$email_subject,$email_content)) {
        echo 'Message sent!'; 
    } else {
        echo 'ERROR!';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: How did you see that form didn't work. Did you have any error?

Comment: This is the massage I get when I click the submit. This page isn’t working www.protekt.co.nz is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Also when I click submit the url reads protekt.co.nz/process.php

Comment: @VaughanT which file is the PHP code from?

Comment: The php code is in process.php file

Comment: I think your server isn't accepting POST requests. You'd either have to contact your hosting provider to enable POST requests, or switch the form to use the GET method instead.

Comment: To know it for sure - you should see webserver logs. Usually 500 error has more detailed description inside the log file - which can lead to a source of an issue and to the solution.

Comment: What version of PHP is the site running on? I ask because `eregi` was removed in 7.0 (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php)

Comment: the site is currently running php 7.1